# List definition - View for AllItems.aspx - How can i display the view with all items and then let the user filter the results

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list definition with a custom form to display all my list items.

I have added 2 controls to filter my view. I want these only to affect the results once the user has chosen a value. Currently the view is being filtered by the default values of the control and not displaying all the items. Should i alter the caml to allow this?

```
 <View BaseViewID="1" Type="HTML" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="$Resources:core,objectiv_schema_mwsidcamlidC24;" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE"
        MobileDefaultView="TRUE"
        SetupPath="pages\toyotatemplate\marketpgviewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="AllItems.aspx" >
    <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
    <XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>
    <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">10</RowLimit>
    <ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" ></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="MarketplaceCategories"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Author"/>
      <FieldRef Name="Created" Format="{dd/mm/yyyy}"/>
      <FieldRef Name="MarketplaceSubCategories"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="Locations"></FieldRef>
      <FieldRef Name="MarketplaceItemExpiryDate" Format="{dd/mm/yyyy}"></FieldRef>
    </ViewFields>
    <Query>
      <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="False" />
      </OrderBy>
    </Query>
    <ParameterBindings>
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
      <ParameterBinding Name="MarketplaceCategories" Location="Control(tcCategories, SelectedItem)"/>
      <ParameterBinding Name="MarketplaceSubcategories" Location="Control(tcSubCategories, SelectedItem)"/>
    </ParameterBindings>
  </View>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this, I created 2 views:

1. AllItems.aspx
2. FilteredItems.aspx.

My control redirects to FilteredItems.aspx on the PostBack and keeps the selected value. The CAML uses the selected value to filter the view.